# Leak or Crash - difference between autorelease and release

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, release, nsdata, autorelease

I have a comprehension question. This method is given:

```
- (NSArray*)test {
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
 NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] 
            length:[data length] 
             encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
 result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"something"];
 NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:result];
 //[result release];
 return arr;
}
```

If I uncomment the `release` the App would crash and say it cannot access a released object.
By not `release`ing the `result` string Instruments would report a leak (NSPlaceholderString).

I can `autorelease` it on the same line I `alloc` it, that would solve the problem (which I'm currently doing in my App).

If I understand it correctly `stringByAppendingString:` should create an autoreleased object so the 'old' result could be deallocated. Then the method `arrayWithObject:` should `copy` the object into an array. So my thought was to release the string after it was copied to the array.

Am I missing something or something wrong with my knowledge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's go through your code line by line.

```
- (NSArray*)test {
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
```

This creates a data object. You don't own it, but it will stick around for the rest of the method's time. So far, so good.

```
 NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] 
                                             length:[data length] 
                                           encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
```

This creates a string object that you own. Again, no problem here — we just need to release it later.

```
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"something"];
```

You throw away your reference to the string object that was in `result` and store a new string object that you do not own. This is a leak because you can no longer release the original string. Also, you're correct in noting that the new string can be treated as an autoreleased object — which means you should not release it.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:result];
```

Contrary to your belief, this does not copy anything. It merely keeps a reference to the new string and retains it.

```
//[result release];
```

You should not release `result` at this point, because the object it contains is not one you own — you got it from `stringByAppendingString:`, not from a method with `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` in its name. Releasing this object that you do not own will almost certainly result in a crash at some point. The old object that you own and *should release* was lost two lines earlier, and releasing something else in its place won't help.

Answer (score 8):

```
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"something"];
```

This line replaces the first allocated string by a new autoreleased string.

So the first string is leaked and the second one should not be released. This explains why uncommenting the release line crashes.

Comment: This is correct.  You can fix it by `autorelease`ing the initial assignment to `result`.

Comment: @Seamus I never asked how to fix this, I wanted an explanation. I already wrote in my question how to fix it so reading the _whole_ question, not only the sample code is helpful.